# Variable not define

Tags: vb6

Hi i need help on this error that i am getting on my code. variable not define and after i define the variable it throws another errors says Method or data member not found and it always highlights the DataEnvironment1.commands. am using a calendar to access my reports. what is likely to be the problem please any help.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

    On Error GoTo e
        frmDate = txtdate1.Text
        endDate = txtdate2.Text

        DataEnvironment1.Commands("InpatientMaintenanceMaster").Parameters(0) = txtdate1
        DataEnvironment1.Commands("InpatientMaintenanceMaster").Parameters(1) = txtdate2
        With RptInpatientMaster
            .Sections("Section2").Controls("lblDate1").Caption = txtdate1.Text
            .Sections("Section2").Controls("lblDate2").Caption = txtdate2.Text
            .Show
        End With
        DataEnvironment1.rsInpatientMaintenanceMaster.Close  
        Unload Me
    Exit Sub

e:
    If Err.Number <> 3704 Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you declared DataEnvironment? Does DataEnvironment1 have a property Commands? If it does, does it then have a property parameters? The error message you are getting is because it cannot find a specified variable. I assume you are not able to build it and it just appears in red? also what type is DataEnvironment1?

Comment: please i have just declare DataEnveronment1 and it throws another error as method or data member not found and not more variable not define.

Comment: Firstly, it should be ....Caption = txtdate1.Text if you want the text value (you were missing the text property). Secondly, you need to think about what the error message is actually saying. Its saying that a method name or data member cannot be found... which method or data member is it?. In that one line, you have 5 possible options either: DataEnvironment1, Commands,Parameters, txtdate1 or Text. Which one is causing issues?

Comment: Also, as an aside, do you need to use VB6? If not then you might want to look at VB.NET  or C# as modern IDE's make it a lot easier to see what's causing issues like this/

Comment: please sir, it highlight  .command

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this line:

```
DataEnvironment1.Commands("InpatientMaintenanceMaster").Parameters(0) = txtdate1
```

And instead replace it with this, and then tell us which line is shown as your error:

```
Dim dataEnv As Object
Set dataEnv = DataEnvironment1

Dim cmd As Object
Set cmd = dataEnv.Commands("InpatientMaintenanceMaster")

Dim dateString As String
dateString = txtdate1.Text 'assuming this is truly a textbox control?

cmd.Parameters(0) = dateString 'should really be using frmDate instead
```

By splitting this out, it should narrow down exactly what you are missing.

Comment: The error has moved to the next line     DataEnvironment1.Commands("InpatientMaintenanceMaster").Parameters(1) = txtdate2

Comment: And after i did same to that line too i now have the error at the very end DataEnvironment1.rsInpatientMaintenanceMaster.Close. with rsInpatientMaintenanceMaster been highlighted. thank you for being there for me.

Comment: In that case temporarily remark out the line with Close and see what the result is.

Comment: Temporarily change `DataEnvironment1.rsInpatientMaintenanceMaster.Close` to `'''DataEnvironment1.rsInpatientMaintenanceMaster.Close`, thus hiding the line you state is showing an error. The goal is to be able to step through your code and see which line is really causing your error, since it is not clear that you figured that out yet.

Comment: Sir it says object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Where?  If you are stepping through the code, on what line did you hit that?

Comment: Please sir it only display the error message but did not show where the error is. and it does not end the program though

Comment: If you don't know how to single-step through a program using the debugger, then you must learn that skill first.  Then come back and try this again.  It is not something that can be taught over Stackoverflow.